# asp.NET - Exclude a Page from Sitemaster or make it follow a different Site Master

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages I want to exclude them from the sitemaster so I can add a check for the session in the sitemaster. I want to exclude them because I want that the 401.aspx page and another page can be accessed by anyone. But the rest should be checked for and authenticated.

Is this possible, and what is the best solution to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't add a `MasterPageFile="~/Master.master"` statement to your pages (or reference another MasterPage here)

Default:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" [...] %>
```

"Special" pages:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AnotherMasterPage.master" [...] %>
```

Without master:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" [...] %>
```

Comment: I just tried that and it works, but I don't believe that's the best possible solution.

Comment: @Geoff Appleford - That if I have say 2-3 pages not referencing the master file, if I want to make a single change I cannot make it on all three pages, I would have to individually change it in all three files.

Comment: Just thought I'd add that if you have a project-wide MasterPage set in the Web.config (system.web > pages) then you can disable it individual pages by setting the MasterPageFile value to blank: <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="" [...] %>

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question your problem is how to handle errors and redirect to specific files when that happens. This may help http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479319.aspx

But if your problem is how to remove master pages from a specific file , you can simply remove it's refrence from your aspx file. remove the  `MasterPageFile="/Master/default.master"`
from your `<%@ Page Language="C#" ...%>`
Hope this helps.